# Pasting Data in Next Blank From "A4"

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, copying, pasting

I have 4 tabs..

Year 1, Year 2, Year 3, Total Spend.

Year 1 pastes in the Total Spend tab like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SegGE.

Now,  I need the data from Year 2 and Year 3 to copy from Row 4 down and pasted into the next row blank in Total Spend.

This is the code I am using to label the Year 2 and 3 range and to attempt to find the first blank cell in column A to paste the data.

I can't figure out why this isn't working.  It doesn't paste anything at any location.

```
    Dim Year2 As Range
Dim Year3 As Range
Dim Location As Range

Set Year2 = Sheets("Year 2 Data").Range("4:4").End(xlDown)
Set Year3 = Sheets("Year 3 Data").Range("4:4").End(xlDown)
Set Location = Sheets("Total Spend").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
If Len(Location.Value) > 0 Then Set Location = Location.Offset(1)


 ' This paste is manual so Row 2 stays blank - this is needed in formatting later on. 

    Sheets("Year 1 Data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Total Spend").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Year2.Copy Location

Year3.Copy Location
```

Comment: You have set `Year2` and `Year3` as the entire column.  There is no where to go down.  Did you intend to start at `Range("A4")`?

Comment: Correction:  from the year 2 and 3 sheet : A3, down and across. Then to be pasted sequentially at the last row of data in the Total Spend sheet,  ignoring the blank row at row 2.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
'    Range(Sheets("Year 2 Data").Range("4:4"), Sheets("Year 2 Data").Range("4:4").End(xlDown))
```

instead of

```
Sheets("Year 2 Data").Range("4:4").End(xlDown)
```

same thing will be apply for Sheets("Year 3 Data")

Comment: Thank you I’ll try this shortly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - it seems to overwrite the previous data and doesn't find the last empty row after the empty row 2.  

Year 1 - There is data in Row 1, Row 2 is blank,  Row 3 has data down to around row 5000.
Year 2 - I need data from Row 3 on wards to be pasted in the next available row after Year 1 data ends
Year 3 - Same as above but when Year 2 data ends. 

I hope this clarifies a little.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the comments,  would something like this be the answer?   (I cannot test it yet as I’ve left work.)

```
Dim Year2 As Range
Dim Year3 As Range
Dim Location As Range

Set Year2 = Range(Sheets("Year 2 Data").Range("4:4"), Sheets("Year 2 Data").Range("4:4").End(xlDown))

Set Year3 = Range(Sheets("Year 3 Data").Range("4:4"), Sheets("Year 3 Data").Range("4:4").End(xlDown))

Set Location = Sheets("Total Spend").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)
```

‘I have changed the above to begin at Row 3, skipping the blank Row 2 so theoretically it would check using the IF from Row 3 down.

```
If Len(Location.Value) > 0 Then Set Location = Location.Offset(1)
```

' This paste is manual so Row 2 stays blank - this is needed in formatting later on.

```
Sheets("Year 1 Data").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Total Spend").Select
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Year2.Copy Location

Year3.Copy Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as per your logic, I think below code will help. It will select the data from sheet, and paste data in output sheet using last row of output sheet.

n A to paste the data.

I can't figure out why this isn't working. It doesn't paste anything at any location.

```
Dim Year2 As Range
```

Dim Year3 As Range
Dim Location As Range

Set Year2 = Range(Sheets("Year 2 Data").Range("4:4"), Sheets("Year 2 Data").Range("4:4").End(xlDown))

Set Year3 = Range(Sheets("Year 3 Data").Range("4:4"), Sheets("Year 3 Data").Range("4:4").End(xlDown))
Set Location = Sheets("Total Spend").Cells(Rows.Count+88, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0)

If Len(Location.Value) > 0 Then Set Location = Location.Offset(1)

' This paste is manual so Row 2 stays blank - this is needed in formatting later on.

```
Sheets("Year 1 Data").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Total Spend").Select
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Sheets("Total Spend").Cells(Rows.Count+88, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).select

Year2.Copy Location

Sheets("Total Spend").Cells(Rows.Count+88, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).select

Year3.Copy Location

Comment: This is giving an error 1004 object defined at: Set Location = Sheets("Total Spend").Cells(Rows.Count+88, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0)

Comment: remove "+88" from rows.count

Answer (score 0):

Ohh! use below code to solve that error. i have removed "+88" from rows.count to solve that error.

```
Set Location = Sheets("Total Spend").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```